# How is network overriding host DNS settings and specific server nslookup?

Tags: networking, dns

I have a weird situation where setting the DNS server in host network settings or application settings (Firefox DoH) is not causing the DNS queries to actually be handled by that server (DNS filter not working).

I'm on a service provider Wi-Fi network that requires portal login.

I've set DNS both on Windows (adapter) and Linux Ubuntu (per network) , but neither are actually resolving with the selected DNS servers.

even when I did nslookup command-line specifying the filter DNS server, the response doesn't match the filtering, or the response when testing using a third party DNS lookup (https://network-tools.com/nslookup/)

Can the network be rerouting all DNS upstream to a different set of servers ?

Comment: The ISP can do anything they want. Try to use a VPN to verify your tests.

Answer (score 1):

If the Wi-Fi requires a portal login, it may be applying a proxy enforced by network policy.  This, paired with the option to route all DNS queries through said proxy, is most likely the reason that your queries are resolving with a different DNS server.

Comment: thanks - I think this may be it


but I would think the host OS settings would still override it, especially when the OS reports using the configured DNS servers. 


do you know how I could check and override the proxy DNS ?

Comment: Try using a VPN (I can provide you one if you need it) and go to https://dnsleaktest.com to check public IP and DNS servers

Comment: yep, I used dnsleaktest to verify the DNS wasn't actually applying the host DNS config. What's even weirder is even specifying the filter server in nslookup, it gives an unfiltered response (not from that DNS server because I checked on different network and it's working).

Comment: So to add some background, it seems the network used Mikrotik DNS forwarding/hijacking - https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Force_users_to_use_specified_DNS_server .


The DoH filter not working was because the trr mode has to be set to `3` in Firefox for the DNS over HTTPS to avoid falling back to the regular DNS on nxdomain responses.